# Can I share a private IP address on Wi-Fi and Ethernet?

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, ethernet, ip

I have a laptop which is usually on Ethernet and has a static IP. Sometimes I need to take it away from my desk and use the wifi. How can I make the Ethernet and Wi-Fi use the same private IP address?

Comment: can you give more details about laptop??

Comment: @Creator: It is an Acer Aspire V3-531 if that's what you mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could configure both interfaces with the same IP, but only one can be active at a time.  To switch from the ethernet connection to the wifi, you could use the following commands.  Someone else may have a much more elegant solution than this.

```
sudo ifdown eth0
sudo ifup wlan0
```

reversing this of course to get back to your ethernet:

```
sudo ifdown wlan0
sudo ifup eth0
```

Answer (score 0):

You could spoof the MAC address of the ethernet device onto the WiFi one. Sounds hard but there's a MAC address box in the Network Manager configuration that makes this a doddle. You can get your current ethernet MAC from the same screens or through `ifconfig -a`.

This should mean that when you connect, `dhclient` will send the same host and MAC to the DHCP server and you should get the same IP.

This could be catastrophic if you connect both at once though. Don't do that.